# Doubleclick the TabItem in Tab Control and View pops up as floating Window

Tags: wpf, popup, tabcontrol

I have a tab control in my mainwindow.xaml file. On startup, when the app runs, all four tabs are shown. Is there a way that once a user double clicks the 'Connect' tab, the entire view of this tab pops up as a new floating window and if I doubleclick the popped up window, it goes back to the initial state?

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" >
       <TabControl Name="ConnectTab" Style="{DynamicResource styleBackground}" />                          
               <tablocal:CloseableTabItem Header="Connect" />
               <tablocal:CloseableTabItem Header="I2C" />
               <tablocal:CloseableTabItem Header="Voltage" />
               <tablocal:CloseableTabItem Header="Clock" />
       </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

**This is my closebutton method for Tab:**

```
 private void CloseTab(object source, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {            
        TabItem tabItem = args.Source as TabItem;

        if (ConnectTab != null && ConnectTab.Items.Count > 1)
            ConnectTab.Items.Remove(tabItem);                     
    }
```

**Closetab class:**

```
public class CloseableTabItem : TabItem
{
    static CloseableTabItem()
    {
        //This OverrideMetadata call tells the system that this element wants to provide a style that is different than its base class.
        //This style is defined in themes\generic.xaml
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CloseableTabItem),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CloseableTabItem)));
    }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent CloseTabEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("CloseTab", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CloseableTabItem));

    public event RoutedEventHandler CloseTab
    {
        add { AddHandler(CloseTabEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(CloseTabEvent, value); }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        Button closeButton = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_Close") as Button;
        if (closeButton != null)
            closeButton.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(closeButton_Click);
    }

    void closeButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(CloseTabEvent, this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you write yourself the code for the CloseableTabItem? Can you post it so we can recreate your scenario?

Comment: @michele: Added the closeabletabitem class. I dont think it makes any difference. I just want a floating window to appear once i doubleclick the tab (lets say CONNECT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept is entirely possible. The problem will be finding the code to do it.

Basically you will need to rehost you TabItem from its current TabControl and host it inside a new TabControl in a new Window. *This code is a simple demonstration of that and should not be considered production quality*

In MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<TabControl Name="myTabControl">
    <TabItem Name ="mytabItem" Header="Double cllick me" MouseDoubleClick="TabItem_MouseDoubleClick">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello world!"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void TabItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myTabControl.Items.Count ==0 ) return;

         myTabControl.Items.Remove(mytabItem);           
        var newWindow = new TempWindow(myTabControl, mytabItem);            
        newWindow.Show();
    }
```

In TempWindow.cs

```
 class TempWindow : Window
{
    private TabControl _original;

    public TempWindow(TabControl original, TabItem tabItem)
    {
        MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(TempWindow_MouseDoubleClick);
        _original = original;
        var tabControl = new TabControl();
        Content = tabControl;

        tabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);
    }

    void TempWindow_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabItem = ((TabControl)Content).Items[0];
        ((TabControl)Content).Items.RemoveAt(0);
        _original.Items.Add(tabItem);

        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with Per, you will really need to handle all sorts of events with moving tabs back in and out. My example relocates the tab but recreatign it would probably be safer in the long term. Have you considered using a docking manager code base?

Comment: A quick search gives you quite a few alternative docking libraries http://www.bing.com/search?q=wpf+docking+manager&form=IE8SRC&src=IE-SearchBox

Comment: Well this looks good. I am able to have a popup but on clicking the title bar of popup, it shud go back to initial state. In your case it goes to maximum state.

Comment: I noticed few issues with your given code above. Once i doubleclick the tabitem, the window pops up. But the tabname along with the inner view also pops up. I only want the content of tab(inner view) to be popped up. i.e. tabitem and X close button shud not pop up. PLus how to disable the max and min buttons on the popped up window?

Comment: sorry i dint notice your 1st comment. Well I tried to use docking manager code base but it didnt work out as expected. Is their a way your given code pops just the content f TABITEM and not the tabite name and close button?

Comment: You can avoid the tabItem appearing by rehosting its content instead of the tabitem. You can set the properties on the window itself to avoid Min, Max, close etc

Comment: this works quite well. I could set the properties of the window to avoid min,max etc...... But still I am not able to avoid the tab item which appears on double click.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is absolutely possible. I'm doing this in one of my applications, but instead of the double-click, I have an icon the user clicks, and when the window is minimized, it is put back among the tabs.

I can't give you a complete solution, but here are a few pointers that should help you get started:

I'm assuming you're using MVVM.

To handle the actual docking/undocking of the view, some work is required. To start with, you should make your view into a UserControl so that you easily can present it in either a window or a tab.

You then need a manger that keeps a reference of the current view for a particular ViewModel, so that you can switch between the two view types (tab or windowed) as needed based on user interaction. This manager will have to create/dispose of tabs and windows, and update the DataContext (your ViewModel) for these.

You'll also need to handle things as window closing events - should the view go back to the tabbed version or close etc etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Per. But I am totally new to this MVVM world. Can you post a sample which does what you are doing with your particluar demo app?? It would be helpful :)

Comment: Sorry but I can't give you the code I'm using. I really recommend you to get acquainted with MVVM, once you get the hang of it it makes working with WPF a lot easier. (Though MVVM isn't the solution for all things).

Comment: ^ I can understand but due to deadline I am really worried.